# is there an easy way to put the selected listbox at the top and not selected last in visual studio?

Tags: c#

hi I am new in c# and I am using visual studio language is C#. is there a way to put the selected item first and the not selected item last in the listbox ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Pi0.png)

I want to know if i can put the selected index 1st and not selected index last ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  `listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;` ?  Is this WinForms?  Wpf?

Comment: Do you want to sort the values according to what is selected?

Comment: You'll have to rephrase the question, because what you're asking is not clear at all -- Also, add a Tag that describes the GUI Platform you're using (as asked in the first comment)

Comment: duerzd696 - yes sort the value according to selected item

Comment: Are you really wanting to sort things based on the selected item?  So every time someone clicks on the item in the list, it resorts it?  Or are you trying to say every new item you add to the list should be the first item in the list?  See `listBox1.Items.Insert(0, "New Item");`

Comment: this is what im trying to do

Comment: i want to sort things base on the selected item